# Kernel 4.13.0-37 and -38 problem when booting to GUI

Tags: boot, kernel

I work with Ubuntu now for over 2 years, but now I have a problem that the automatic installer installed kernel 4.13.0-37 and after that the boot procedures were not completed.

I can see the normal boot output messages, but then it switches to a black blank screen with a mouse cursor (which cannot move).

So maybe there is a problem in starting the desktop manager?

I tried also to install 4.13.0-38, same problems.

4.13.0.-36 works fine.

As I do not know which further information (e.g. from syslog) is needed, please ask.

My setup: X86 with i5-3570 cpu and Ubuntu version 17.04 with Mate desktop

**Update:**

Now I removed the microcode to go back to:

```
[    1.835022] microcode: sig=0x306a9, pf=0x2, revision=0x15
[    1.851062] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

Then reboot to 4.13.0-38 was successful!

After switching back to new microcode it fails again:

```
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[    0.752400] microcode: sig=0x306a9, pf=0x2, revision=0x1c
[    0.752550] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

Btw, 0x1c seems to be the newest kernel driver offered by Ubuntu appgrid. According to the list from Intel it should be 0x1f. Strange..

Comment: Perhaps this is a far fetched explanation but I strongly advise you to re-download the the 3 deb files responsible for 4.13.0-38 - the two deb packages containing the headers + the image file and do this twice in two different directories. Then when done, run `crc32` against each file including the one that gives you issues. Are you getting the same hash values? The aim is to check if the downloaded files are downloaded correctly.

Comment: I can do this, but I do not think that both versions -37 and -38 were corrupt. I always do an upgrade from official (Ubuntu) sources.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I realized that after I posted my response and the other thing I failed to consider before I typed was whether you are using the Software Updater or installing deb files manually. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, any hints are welcome ;-)

Comment: For comparison purposes, my microcode is working fine: `microcode: sig=0x506e3, pf=0x20, revision=0xba` and then `microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.`.

Comment: It seems that the ubuntu microcode package is not up-to-date.
When I install the microcode package it says the package it is from 2018 (latest), but version number inside in dmesg is from 2015 (old).

Comment: This problem is probably related to the following bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1759920
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1761121

Comment: I guess I have the same issue. How  do you rollback the microcode?

Comment: Please try     
    sudo apt-get remove intel-microcode

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Just waiting for 4.13.0-39 I suppose.